# No tengo ni la menor idea de quién / a quién / con quién / sobre quién estás hablando?

Tags: sintaxis

Unos amigos y yo llevamos un momento discutiendo sobre la manera correcta de traducir la siguiente frase al español.

> I don't have the faintest idea who you're talking about.

Unos de dichos amigos han sugerido lo siguiente:

> No tengo ni la menor idea de quién estás hablando.

Para mí eso no tiene sentido, suena como si se le quitara el "about" a la frase inglesa:

> I don't have the faintest idea who you're talking [...].

Unos han sugerido las opciones siguientes:

> No tengo ni la menor idea de a quién estás hablando.

> No tengo ni la menor idea de con quién estás hablando.

> No tengo ni la menor idea de sobre quién estás hablando.

Querría que alguien me explicase cuál(es) de todas esas versiones es (son) correcta(s), y por qué. Se puede omitir el "de" para evitar la redundancia, como en la siguiente frase?

> No tengo ni la menor idea sobre quién estás hablando.

Gracias por adelantado por vuestra respuestas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando el término de una preposición comienza con una preposición, éstas no deben coincidir.

Coloquialmente, estoy de acuerdo en que la oración que sugiere la otra respuesta sería entendible y probablemente la más usada:

> No tengo ni la menor idea de quién estás hablando.

No obstante, gramaticalmente se produce una superposición entre la preposición regida por el sustantivo "idea", que introduce un complemento de régimen:

- No tengo ni la menor idea **de** algo.

y la preposición que inicia el término y que introduce el circunstancial de tema de la proposición nominal que funciona como término:

- Estás hablando **de** alguien.

Obviamente, no podemos decir:

(*) No tengo ni la menor idea ***de de*** quién estás hablando.

Algunas alternativas gramaticalmente correctas que se me ocurren son:

- No tengo ni la menor idea **de acerca de** quién estás hablando.
- No tengo ni la menor idea de quién es la persona de la que/de quien estás hablando.
- No tengo ni la menor idea de la persona de la que/de quien estás hablando.

El mismo problema puede surgir con otras preposiciones, por ejemplo:

- Estoy de acuerdo **con** algo. / Estás tratando **con** alguien.

NO es posible decir:

(*) Estoy de acuerdo ***con con*** quien estás tratando.

Una alternativa gramatical sería:

- Estoy de acuerdo **con** que estés tratando **con** X persona.

Otro ejemplo:

- Quedamos en algo / Nos encontraremos en un lugar.

NO podemos decir:

(*) Quedamos ***en en*** dónde nos encontraremos.

Una alternativa gramatical sería:

- Quedamos **en** que nos encontraremos **en** X lugar.
- Quedamos en el lugar donde nos encontraremos.

Answer (score 0):

La opción mas acertada y que he escuchado sería:

```
No tengo ni la menor idea de quién estás hablando
```